# How can we run a docker compose with .env in another directory?

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, subdirectory, docker-machine

I am creating a **docker compose** file in a root directory with some **id** variable passing to it for volume creation using .env file, but one thing is I am creating a new directory for every **id** and placing **.env** in that directory, can we able to point this **.env** to pass parameters to the docker compose in root. Because I read some articles where that both need to reside in the same directory.

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
xyz:
  image: xyz
  environment:
    ID: "${ID}"


 ports:
    - "XYZ:XYZ"
 volumes:
    - /XYZ${ID}:/data
```

Which will be basically in sub directory example in 1234 directory

.env file

```
ID=1234
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in official [page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) you can either override default path with:

```bash
docker compose --env-file ./config/.env.dev config
```

or start container with:

```bash
docker compose --env-file ./config/.env.dev up
```

There is also an option to define it in `docker-compose.yaml` fila as:

```
xyz:
  env_file:
    - /path-to/web-variables.env
```

Comment: I am not sure if last example will work. Value for ID will not be substituted

Comment: According to the official documentation it should work. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#env_file

Comment: It doesn't 
```
version: "3.9"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:${TAG}
    env_file:
      - .test.env
```
* oupput

```
docker compose config
WARN[0000] The "TAG" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
name: tmp
services:
  postgres:
    environment:
      TAG: "1.4"
    image: 'postgres:'
    networks:
      default: null
networks:
  default:
    name: tmp_default
```